# Django error on fly io app: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_session

Tags: django, sqlite, fly

I have a Django application deployed on fly.io
Sometimes when I do a database operation like login, signup, or a CRUD operation, it returns the error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_session".
I think it's important to note I'm using sqlite3

I logged in to the fly ssh console and executed the commands:
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
But the error is still showing almost every time I do a database operation from the UI of my app